What are the two non-intersecting ellipses with biggest joint area that can be inscribed into regular triangle?
Given regular triangle $ABC$ we want to find two non-intersecting ellipses with biggest joint area, inscribed in it (not demanding that ellipses touch sides of triangle or touch each other, they simply need to be inside of $ABC$).
Hypothetical optimal ellipses are shown on picture below, bigger ellipse of the two, ellipse $O$, is inner circle of $ABC$ and smaller ellipse, ellipse $O’$, is inner circle of regular triangle $EFC$, where $EF$ is parallel to $AB$ and tangent to ellipse $O$ at point $D$. Putting ellipse $O’$ into any of the other two corners of $ABC$ gives, of course, the same joint area of $O$ and $O’$. Prove that joint area of $O$ and $O’$ is maximal possible or find better ellipses.


I believe you can get a better result if you keep the smaller ellipse a circle that's tangent to the $2$ sides and stays on top of the larger ellipse (just like in your solution), but you make the large ellipse "fatter", so the smaller one has more room to be on top of it. Specifically, I tried the large ellipse be tangent to all $3$ triangle sides but have its minor semi-axis (which is vertical) to be around $\frac{23}{3 (4 + \sqrt{85})} \approx 0.57$ times its major semi-axis (which is horizontal).

@Vladimir_U How did you got your conclusions? Can you give us a hint?

I don't even know how to cover the maximum area with one ellipse inscribed in an equilateral triangle.  Is it a circle?

You can solve for the top ellipse first because the top triangle is equilateral by symmetry.  I suspect the answer is a circle.  Having done that, you know what fraction of the top triangle is filled and can take a derivative with respect to the vertical position of EF.

The top triangle is obtained by cutting off the main triangle with the tangent line of the two ellipses.  It's equilateral if the tangent line is parallel to the base, but I don't know how to prove that's the optimal configuration.

@MJD For any triangle, the largest inscribed ellipse is Steiner inellipse, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/828017/255730 The ratio of the areas is in that case ${2\pi\over3\sqrt3}$.

Thanks. I'll summarize: for an equilateral triangle $T$ the maximal ellipse is the usual incircle. For another triangle $T'$, find an affine transform that maps $T$ to $T'$. The image of the the incircle of $T$ is the maximum ellipse for $T'$.

Thanks to user3257842 and all other, I found indeed that bigger ellipse is not inner circle, I posted my answer, it is not perfect even for symmetric problem formulation because I still need to take derivative of a complicated function which I came up with but I plan to do it later

@MJD we can characterize the maximum elipse by its affine-invariant properties: namely, it is the ellipse that is tangent to all sides of the triangle, where the points of tangence are the exactly midpoints of the sides.

I'll give another answer just to show another method and to give an exact result, which is in agreement with the solution posted by the OP. I'll make the same assumptions, i.e. an equilateral triangle (of unit side) is divided into a triangle and a trapezoid by a line parallel to one side. We inscribe a circle into the triangle and an ellipse into the trapezoid (with an axis parallel to the bases). We want to find the placement of the line, so that the sum of the areas of the inscribed conics be a maximum.
Let's set $t=AE$ (see figure below) and $1-t=CE=EF$ (note that $0\le t\le1$). The vertical semi-axis of the ellipse is then:
$$
b=OD={\sqrt3\over4}t.
$$
The line joining the tangency points of the ellipse passes through the intersection point $P$ of the diagonals of the trapezoid (because trapezoid and ellipse can be seen as the perspective images of a square with its inscribed circle). From the similarity of triangles $ABP$, $EFP$ we get then:
$$
PD={\sqrt3\over2}{t(1-t)\over2-t}
\quad\text{and}\quad
PO=b-PD={\sqrt3\over4}{t^2\over2-t}.
$$
Moreover:
$$
PT=DE+{PD\over\sqrt3}={1-t\over2-t}.
$$
We can now obtain the other semiaxis $a=OG$ from the ellipse equation:
$$
{PT^2\over a^2}+{PO^2\over b^2}=1
\quad\implies\quad
a={1\over2}\sqrt{1-t}.
$$
We can now compute the area of the ellipse $\pi ab$ as a function of $t$ and sum to that the area of the circle, whose radius is $\sqrt3(1-t)/6$:
$$
A_\text{ellipse}+A_\text{circle}=f(t)=
{\sqrt3\over8}\pi t\sqrt{1-t}+{\pi\over12}(1-t)^2.
$$
To find the maximum of $f(t)$ we must solve $f'(t)=0$, which after some algebra boils down to
$$
27(2-3t)^2=64(1-t)^3.
$$
This is a cubic equation, but it has an integer solution $t=-2$. Factoring that out we are left with a quadratic equation, whose only acceptable solution is:
$$
t={77-3\sqrt{33}\over128}.
$$
Inserting that into $f(t)$ we can find the maximum area;
dividing the result by the area of the triangle ($\sqrt3/4$) we finally get the maximum ratio:
$$
\frac{9 \left(13 \sqrt{3}+55 \sqrt{11}\right) \pi }{8192}
\approx 0.707311
$$


Thanks a lot, intelligenti pauca, I accepted your answer as it gives me opportunity not to dive into derivative of my non-easy function above, I fine tuned my numerical calculation and found that my function has exactly the maximum you give 0.707311, so my assumption that ratio AT/AC (in your picture) is exactly cos(π*2/5) was wrong, it is slightly different and can be found exactly based on your calculation.

Please take a look at my next question related to this optimization problem, if it is answered positively, I believe it will follow that symmetric composition of 2 ellipses is the best solution if we do not demand them to be symmetric inside equilateral triangle. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5012942/prove-that-triangle-ade-is-bigger-than-triangle-ad-e-and-triangle-afg-is-smalle/5012971#5012971

Solving problem above in full looks complicated to me now, below I give answer only to symmetric case, when both ellipses $O$ and $O’$ must have one their half axis along vertical axis of symmetry of triangle $ABC$. One comment above suggested that bigger ellipse can be not inner circle of $ABC$ but have longer horizontal half-axis, this idea turns out to be true.
First let’s note that optimal solution will have same ratio for sum of ellipses area to area of $ABC$ for all isosceles triangles because ellipses stay ellipses under linear transform of stretching along vertical axis and areas increase/decrease with same ratio for triangle $ABC$ and for ellipses under this transform. Let’s denote ratio of sum of ellipses area to area of $ABC$ as $Ratio$ and maximal possible ratio as $RatioMax$.
Let’s transform one of such isosceles triangles optimally filled by two ellipses (with $RatioMax$)  into isosceles triangle where bigger ellipse (one that touches side $AB$) is inner circle of $ABC$ after this transform, as shown on $picture 1$ below. We can calculate value of $∠CAB$ that leads to maximal $Ratio$ as shown below.

Assume that:
$$AB = 1; ∠CAB = x;$$
It follows that:
$$AH = AG = 0,5$$
$$tg{(∠CAB)} = \sqrt \frac{1 - cos(x)}{1 + cos(x)}$$
$$OG = AG* tg{(∠CAB)}$$
$$∠GED =\pi-x$$
$$ED = \frac{OG}{tg(\frac{∠GED}{2})}$$
$$area(AEFB) =2*OG*AG+2*OG*ED$$
$$area(ABC) =AH*AH*tg(x)$$
$$area(ECF) =area(ABC)-area(AEFB)$$
Because $O’$ is Steiner ellipse for triangle ECF:
$$\frac{area(O')}{area(ECF)} =\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt3} = 0,6046...$$
From above we can obtain expression for $Ratio$ as function of $x$, which is rather complicated, but numerical calculation of this formula clearly suggest maximal $Ratio$ at $x = (2/5)*\pi = 72 degrees$, as shown on function values plot below, this implies that point $G$ where bigger ellipse touches $AC$, divides side $AC$ with ratio $AG / AC = cos(2*\pi/5) = 0,309…$ Resulting optimal ellipses for equilateral triangle are shown on $picture 2$ below.
$$Ratio(x) =\pi*((1-cos(x))/(1+cos(x)))/tg(x)+(0,25*tg(x)-(0,5*\sqrt{(1-cos(x))/(1+cos(x))}+0,5*((1-cos(x))/(1+cos(x)))/tg((\pi-x)/2)))*(\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt3})/(0,25*tg(x))$$


I agree that this solution is not complete as I didn’t calculate derivative of formula for $Ratio(x)$ to prove that $72 degrees$ is really the maximum, but it can be done later, overall picture is clear anyways, I just want to note that my approach (transforming problem into triangle where optimal bigger ellipse is inner circle) opens way to solution of the next problem that I had in mind – what are the tree non-intersecting ellipses of the biggest joint area that can be inscribed into equilateral triangle?

Hint: calculating in terms of angles seems complicated. For my derivation I just assumed $AH = 1$, and $CH = h$ (here I'm referring to the stretched triangle). The height $h$ is the only unknown, so you may calculate everything in terms of $h$. The large circle radius is the ratio of the area to the semi-perimeter, Giving $r = \frac{h}{1+\sqrt{h^2+1}}$. This choice of variables simplifies a lot of the calculations.

can well be... frankly I had no time so far to work with derivative, if it is easier when using your h instead of my x, I will try of course, thanks a lot! I am thinking more now in a direction of how to solve general case, not just symmetric, solution should be the same, but proving it may be not that easy...

I'm sure the best solution is a symmetric one, but I haven't been able to prove it. One reason it's so difficult is that for a convex quadrilateral (which is what you get by subtracting the small triangle from the large one), there is a whole family of possible ellipses that  are tangent to all four sides.  Just saying the ellipse is tangent to all fours does not give you a unique solution.

no need to talk about ellipse, same trick with linear transform I used above makes large ellipse (touching 3 sides of the triangle) an inner circle of transformed triangle and this can be used to prove that symmetric position of ellipses is a solution for general case, not sure 100% but will try to compile this part of proof soon, if you will have more ideas about proving that Ratio function above (maybe expressed in terms of h) has exactly one maximum and value of x or h when this maximum is reached please let me know...

I posted new question, which, if answered positively, I believe, implies that general solution for two largest ellipses in equilateral triangle can be only symmetric

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5012942/prove-that-triangle-ade-is-bigger-than-triangle-ad-e-and-triangle-afg-is-smalle
