Prove that triangle ADE is bigger than triangle AD’E’ and triangle AFG is smaller than triangle AF’G’ or find counterexample
Two intersecting lines $AB$ and $AC$ are touching circle $O$ at points $B$ and $C$, $∠CAB <= \pi /3$, , points $D,D’,F,F’$ are on line $AB$ and points $E,E’,G,G’$ are on line $AC$ as shown on picture, intervals $DE,D’E’,FG,F’G’$ are touching circle $O$, so that $DA = EA, FA = GA$, while $D’A≠E’A,F’A≠G’A$. Prove that triangle $ADE$ is bigger than triangle $AD’E’$ and triangle $AFG$ is smaller than triangle $AF’G’$ or find counterexample. Is result the same for $∠CAB > \pi /3$?


We note area of a triangle of vertex $A,B,C$ simply as $\triangle{ABC}$.
Let point $O'=\overline{DE}\cap\overline{D'E'}$.
By construction, $O'$ it is located to the left of vertical $AO$ which implies that $\triangle{DO'E'}\lt\triangle{EO'E'}$ so $\triangle{EO'E'}-\triangle{DO'E'}\gt0$. Since
$$\triangle{AD'E'}=\triangle{ADE}-\triangle{EO'E'}+\triangle{DO'D'}$$ then
$$\triangle{ADE}\gt\triangle{AD'E'}$$
Similarly reasoning, because now point $O''=\overline{FG}\cap\overline{F'G'}$ is located to the right of vertical $AO$, leads to $$\triangle{AFG}\lt\triangle{AF'G'}$$

Why AD'E' = ADE - EO'E' + DO'E? is not it AD'E' = ADE - EO'E' + DO'D'?

@Vladimir_U: It was a slip of the pen. Thank you very much.

now I don't see how you prove that EO'E>DO'D', line above corrected equation says that EO'E'>DO'E' (with that I agree), not EO'E'>DO'D'

@Vladimir_U: Because of the fact O′
it is located to the left of vertical AO You know the area is equal to the half of product of two sides by the sinus of the angle (in this case a common angle).

If you sure that this all works I trust you. I posted already my own proof that I understand 100%, I needed this problem solution as auxiliary lemma for another optimization problem (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5012151/what-are-the-two-non-intersecting-ellipses-with-biggest-joint-area-that-can-be-i), where I need to show that symmetric position of two ellipses is better than any asymmetric, so I wanted to be sure that I have a proof for this statement, Thanks for your effort!

@Vladimir_U: It was easy, without effort. You are welcome.

Because answer given above is not convincing to me (I believe that author wrongly assumed that he solved the problem or something important is missing in his text) I came up with the following proof.
Let’s denote intersection of $DE$ and $D’E’$ as $H$ and intersection of $FG$ and $F’G’$ as $I$, $J$ and $K$ – points where $DE$ and $D’E’$ are toughing circle $O$, $L$ and $M$ – points where $FG$ and $F’G’$ are toughing circle $O$, as on picture below.
We have:
$HJ = HK$; $D’K = D’B$ (note that $D’K ≠ HK$ in general, although it looks like that on picture);
$JE = EC = DB > D’B = D’K => JE > D’K => HJ + JE > HJ + D’K = HK + D’K => HE > HD’$
Denote $N$ a point inside interval $HE$ such that $HN = HD’$
Denote $P$ a point on ray $HE’$ such that $∠HNP = ∠HD’D$
Because $∠HD’D < ∠HDA$ and $∠HEA = ∠HDA$ we conclude that $P$ is inside interval $HE’$, it follows that $△HNP = △HD’D$ and $△HNP$ is inside $△HEE’$, thus $△HEE’ > △HDD’$ and we proved that $△ADE > △AD’E’$ for any value of $∠CAB$.
Following similar steps we prove that point $Q$ on ray $IF$ such that $IQ = IG’$ is inside $LF$ and point $R$ on ray $IF’$ such that $∠IQR = ∠IG’G$ is inside $IF’$, concluding that $△AFG < △AF’G’$ for any value of $∠CAB$.


It is clear that $$\frac{\overline{HD}\times\overline{HD'}}{2}\sin(\alpha)\lt\frac{\overline{HE}\times\overline{HE'}}{2}\sin(\alpha)$$ implies the inequality you wish.
